# PowerShell access parameter value passed

Tags: powershell, solarwinds-orion

I am  running a external program on SolarWinds   which calls PowerShell script and i am passing hostname as a parameter to my script .

param(
$hostname
)

$hostname1 ="$($hostname)"

$hostname1 |Out-File D:\hostname.txt

---

output in hostname.txt is

${N=SwisEntity;M=F5Device.Node.DisplayName}

---

how can i get the  value of hostname (value of  F5Device.Node.DisplayName  ) ..?

Comment: `"_i am passing hostname as a parameter to my script_"`... Show us what you are sending as parameter

Comment: hi @theo ..  Below is the command  i put on tool when i select run a external program. 
                                
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command "& {& "D:\Auto-Inc\VRO_PROD-script-v2.ps1" -hostname '${N=SwisEntity;M=F5Device.Node.DisplayName}' -triggertime '${N=Alerting;M=AlertTriggerTime;F=DateTime}' -ObjectURL '${N=SwisEntity;M=DetailsUrl}' -Alertdetails '${N=Alerting;M=AlertDescription}' -AcknowledgeUrl '${N=Alerting;M=AcknowledgeUrl}' -alertname '${N=Alerting;M=AlertName}' -alertdefination '${N=Alerting;M=AlertName}' }"

Comment: --------D:\Auto-Inc\VRO_PROD-script-v2.ps1----------------

param(
$hostname,
$alertdefination,
$alertname,
$triggertime,
$ObjectURL,
$Alertdetails,
$AcknowledgeUrl
)

$hostname1 ="$($hostname)"

$hostname1 |Out-File D:\hostname.txt

Comment: @TarunGupta, did you get the chance to make it work? Please share the solution here.